# Passing Set-Cookie from external server in getServerSideProps to browser

Tags: next.js, graphql, session-cookies, apollo-client, getserversideprops

I am trying to fetch some data via Apollo Client during SSR in the NextJS `getServerSideProps` method from an external graphql server.
The server response has a `Set-Cookie` header with a session id.
Later on, however, I also want to send queries from the client side to the same external grahpql server, but the `Set-Cookie` header received in the `getServerSideProps` is not passed to the browser, so the graphlq server has no clue that this still should be the same session.

Is there a way to automatically pass the `Set-Cookie` received during SSR to the browser and later automatically use the cookie from the browser during subsequent SSR queries?

Essentially using SSR as a pass-through between the browser and the external server.

Additional info: CORS is enabled on the graphql server, they are all on the same domain, `credentials: 'same-origin'` is set on the apollo client and thus there isn't any cors related issue

I've tried using the `next-cookie` package to set already existing broswer cookies for the apollo-client queries during SSR, however, I haven't been able to pass the `Set-Cookie` received during SSR to the browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.